# Rickshaw smooth update transition

Tags: d3.js, plot, real-time, rickshaw

I'm working on something close to that [example](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/fixed.html) and I was wondering if there is a way to specify a transition function to be applied at each draw. I find the constant jumping hurts my eyes and I'd like to use something like:

`d3.transition().duration(step).transition("linear")`

but it have the gut feeling rickshaw's internals won't allow for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had my go at it here:
https://github.com/RenaudF/d3-plugins/commit/c16dd3bc5558e1974a08bb26fcdb084e7afa9b12

But it turns out that the points are transitioning  on their vertical axis instead of from right to left, which makes things worse if anything.